# Replace/Convert via sql while querying csv

Tags: sql, excel, csv, replace, adodb

I'm trying to query a CSV via ADODB/SQL and the results need to be ordered by date. The challenge is that the date is in dd-mon-yy format. I tried to use **CONVERT** and **REPLACE** but Excel 2003 keeps throwing Automation Error at me. I've tried both of the following separately.

With CONVERT:

```
"SELECT CONVERT(datetime,[Business Date],106) from [filename.csv]"
```

With REPLACE:

```
"SELECT REPLACE([Business Date],'-',' ') from [filename.csv]"
```

I don't have control over the CSV so manually correcting the dates is not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
 SELECT CDate(Right([Business Date],2) & "/" _
    & Mid([Business Date],4,3) & "/" _
    & Left([Business Date],2)) from [filename.csv]
```

Depending, of course, on your locale. I do not believe Convert and Replace are available to ADO.

Comment: You're missing the closing bracket for CDATE. The following worked for me. Thanks. SELECT CDate(Left([Business Date],2) & "/" & Mid([Business Date],4,3) & "/" & Right([Business Date],2)) from [filename.csv]

Comment: @fasih.ahmed Another thought, with `yy` format you may run into problems with ambiguous dates. It may be best to add another couple of digits to the year, if you can.

Comment: Good suggestion but this is one of those big corporations thing where getting this changed would take atleast a year. If I was controlling the data, I would format it yyyy.mm.dd because in that case sorting based on lexical order or unixtime would produce the same result.